# CSS gradient not rendering in Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser Control

Tags: css, windows-phone-8

I am facing an issue where, the CSS3 background is not rendered in WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8. But same HTML when opened in WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8, it renders the gradient

The HTML I am using is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
        <div id="im_c" style="height:48px;width:100%25;  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
             bottom,                
             #432100 30%,               
             #00AAAA 70%);"> 
            <div style="margin:0 auto;width:320px;">
                Test
                </div> 

        </div> 
        <style> 
            body {margin:0px} 
        </style> 
</body>
```

In Windows Phone 8, I use the HTML as below:

```
WebBroswer WebView = new WebBrowser();
WebView.Height = 100;
WebView.Width = 400;
WebView.NavigateToString(@"<html><head><meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=320, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1""/></head><body style=""margin:0px;overflow:hidden;""> <div id=""im_c"" style=""height:48px;width:100%25; background: -ms-linear-gradient(         bottom,                 #432100 30%,                #00AAAA 70%);""> <div style=""margin:0 auto;width:320px;"">Test</div></div> <style> body {margin:0px} </style> </body></html>");
```

In this case, the CSS gradient is not visible.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

The WebBrowser control is running in IE5 Quirks mode and gradients are not available in that mode.